# Can I change page title in reactjs in this way (using useState and useEffect)?

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why it's not working. Does it have any syntax error tho?

```
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("My Financial Right Hand");
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = pageTitle;
}, [pageTitle]);
function changePageTitle(props) {
    setPageTitle(props);
};
```

and inside render:

```
{changePageTitle("Main Page")}
```

Comment: For dynamic page titles I would suggest to use [React-Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) Sorry if it's not what you need.

Comment: @ldruskis Actually I thought of it also but it's gonna make my code super complicated. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Actually it won't complicate things. `<title>{title}</title>`. And you're good to go!

Comment: @ldruskis I found what I was looking for. Check below. He actually solved it smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try implementing a custom hook

```
export function useTitle(title) {
 useEffect(() => {
    const prevTitle = document.title
    document.title = title
      return () => {
         document.title = prevTitle
      }
  })
}
```

call the function as below

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  useTitle("New Title")
 return (
   <div>
     ...
   </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what could solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: np , happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `react-helmet` which runs as a side effect to change the title, metadata ...etc.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

export default function App() {
  const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("My Financial Right Hand");

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>{pageTitle}</title>
      </Helmet>
      <p>tsample text</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit brave-stitch-hnt31f]

Comment: Why is this better than the accepted answer? `react-helmet` is great for modifying `<head>` content, but if all that's needed is a title change, it seems a bit heavy-handed to introduce a new dependency